# How to get a while loop to start over after error?

Tags: python, while-loop

would like to say I still feel fairly new too python in general. But I have a movie recommender system that I have been working on, and the way I have it setup is for the user to enter a movie in the console and then it spits out 10 recommendations and ask for another movie.
When a misspelled movie is entered, it gives error message `KeyError: 'Goodfellas'` and it stops running.
I would like for it to just start the loop over, until the user ends the loop using my break word. Here is my code for reference.

```
while True:
    user_input3 = input('Please enter movie title: ')
    if user_input3 == 'done':
        break
    print(get_input_movie(user_input3))
```

get_input_movie() is the function I am using to "select" the top 10 movies. Is this possible? Was not able to find much online. Thanks!

Also I am pulling data from a pandas dataframe and using TfidfVectorizer for my similarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`try-except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) and [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html):

```
while True:
    user_input3 = input('Please enter movie title: ')
    if user_input3 == 'done':
        break
    try:
        print(get_input_movie(user_input3))
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

Comment: perfect thanks some reason couldn't nail it.

Answer (score 1):

To continue after an `KeyError` exception you should use a `try` block inside your loop, example:

```py
try:
    ... # Here goes your code that can result in a KeyError exception
except KeyError:
    continue
```